# When to use 座る vs 坐る

Tags: kanji, kanji-choice

As I'm starting to explore more kanji, I've come across these two ways of writing すわる (to sit): 座る and 坐る.

I would like to know when to use one over the other. Are there nuances that would make one very inappropriate to use in a special setting? Is one being used for sitting with a roof over one's head (a house) vs under open sky (on a bench in a park)?

Comment: 坐 is old school 座. Now, you might only see the former in books and museums (it's quite common to see 坐像{ざぞう}). May be there are nuances but I never heard of.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To built up a bit on my comment (*坐 is old school 座. Now, you might only see the former in books and museums (it's quite common to see 坐像{ざぞう}). May be there are nuances but I never heard of.*) 語源-allguide has an entry on 座る.

> 【意味】 座るとは、膝を折り曲げて腰を下ろす。ある地位や役に就く。
>
> 【座るの語源・由来】
>   座るは、落ち着いて動かないことを表す「据わる（すわる）」と同源。
>   「居ても立ってもいられない」と言うように、古く、「立つ」の対義語は「居る」であった。
>   平安時代末頃から、「居る」が「存在する」といった意味で多く用いられるようになったことから、他動詞「すう（据う）」が自動詞化した「すわる」が、「立つ」の対義語として用いられるようになった。
>   漢字の「坐」は「人＋人＋土」で、地面に尻をつけることを示している。
>   「座」の漢字は、「广（いえ）＋坐」で、家の中で人が座る場所のことである。
>   「坐」が動詞、「座」が名詞として用いられたが、常用漢字では「座」に統一された。

Translation:

> 座る means *bend your knees and seat your rear*. Or, be employed at a position.
>
> [Etymology of 座る]
>   座る shares its etymology with 据｛す｝わる and means *being calm without moving*.
>   As seen in [「居｛い｝ても立ってもいられない」](https://kotobank.jp/word/%E5%B1%85%E3%81%A6%E3%82%82%E7%AB%8B%E3%81%A3%E3%81%A6%E3%82%82%E5%B1%85%E3%82%89%E3%82%8C%E3%81%AA%E3%81%84-436527)(boils at the core but can't afford not keeping calm), the antonym of 立つ was 居る.
>   Since, by the end of the Heian era, 居る became used a lot in the meaning of *to exist*  the transitive verb 据｛す｝う turned into the intransitive verb 据｛す｝わる and (すわる) started to be used as the antonym of 立つ.
>   The kanji 坐 is made of 人＋人＋土 and means to seat one's rear on the ground (as you have guessed in your question).
>   The kanji 座 is made of 广（いえ）＋坐 and refers to a place where one would seat in a house.
>   坐 was used as a verb, whereas 座 was used as a noun. But this 坐 is not a 常用漢字, 座 is now used for both.

Answer (score 2):

坐る is very rarely used.
I have seen it little.

As far as I searched, 坐る was a Kanji for a verb, and 座 was a Kanji for a noun that means a place to sit in early Showa era.
Though the government enacted the following rules in Showa 31th(1956).
http://kokugo.bunka.go.jp/kokugo_nihongo/joho/kakuki/03/pdf/doon.pdf
×
坐→座

It seems that they were unified into one Kanji by this rules.
That is to say, 坐 is old Kanji.